# how to stop our blinking flashlight in android

Tags: android

I am making a app flashlight.....but i want to stop my blinking led flashlight ...this is my code but i am not able to stop my blinking flashlight..

```
String  myString = "010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101011";
long blinkDelay = 50;

for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
    if (myString.charAt(i) == '0') {
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        cam.setParameters(p);
    }
    else {
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        cam.setParameters(p);
    }
    Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);
}
}catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: So this is a separate thread to UI thread and something the UI will stop the flash?

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about thread-safety as the code running this loop should be on a separate thread. Setting a `boolean` to stop safely would require an `AtomicBoolean` at least but it's far easier to use a different technique altogether, the `AsyncTask` which is already cancellable and doesn't require you to create and manage a new thread directly:

```
package com.stackoverflow.blinker;

import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public final class Blinker extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private final long blinkDelay = 50;
    private final Camera cam;
    private boolean on;

    public Blinker(Camera cam) {
        this.cam = cam;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while (!isCancelled()) {
            toggleLight();
            try {
                wait(getBlinkDelay());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                break;
            }
        }
        setFinalLightState();
        return null;
    }

    private void setFinalLightState() {
        // optionally turn off at the end
        setOn(false);
    }

    private long getBlinkDelay() {
        // want to have light on for a different time to it is off? do this:
        // return isOn() ? blinkDelayOn : blinkDelayOff;
        return blinkDelay;
    }

    private void toggleLight() {
        setOn(!isOn());
    }

    public boolean isOn() {
        return on;
    }

    public void setOn(boolean on) {
        this.on = on;
        Camera.Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
        if (on) {
            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        } else {
            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        }
        cam.setParameters(p);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
//create
Blinker b = new Blinker(Camera.open());
//start
b.execute();
//stop
b.cancel(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop make a condition.

for example make a private variable of your class:

```
boolean stop = false;
```

Check it in the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; (i < myString.length()) && !stop; i++) {
   ....
}
```

And somewhere in your code:

```
stop = true;
```

Comment: No consideration for thread-safety here. As `stop = true` isn't going to be in the loop is it? Therefore it's not going to be called by the same thread.

Comment: I don't see any harm with a flashlights that may blink one more time because changing the boolean was not an atomic action.

Comment: That's not the consequence at all. The compiler or JIT is allowed to optimize that conditional check outside the `for` loop. After all why keep checking it if the loop will not modify it? Will it do this? That is undefined, but it has the option to. This means it might work in one compiler/JIT but not in another. You should read up on the point of `volatile` keyword. As that would be another solution to this and highlights the problem. Look at this page and read the part with the `isActive boolean` http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/volatile-keyword-java-example-tutorial.html